# Can I use the Google Elevation API for academic research (licensing)?

Tags: api, elevation, google, research, license

I would like to use the Google Elevation API to generate about 5 elevation maps for master's degree research on aircraft collision avoidance. The data would be meshed and used in simulation to calculate trajectory intersections of aircraft with the terrain.

I know the terms and conditions state that the data must be displayed in conjunction with a Google Map. If I publish my thesis with the meshed elevation data alongside a Google map of the area - is it allowed? What else would I need to do to be able to use the data for this purpose? The amount of data I need is within the usage limits.

Comment: The Elevation API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using elevation data without displaying a map for which elevation data was requested is prohibited. You would need to contact Google. This is for interactive services not published thesis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NASA SRTM data instead.

http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/

https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search/granules?p=C1000000240-LPDAAC_ECS&q=SRTM

The data is indexed by integer degree of latitude and longitude